# Find element in ArrayList by conditions and return him or null by lambda

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

I have collection of custom objects, and I need in my function find the correct one by id property, and return him. If element with that id won't found function return null. Can you help me fix my code? Here is it:

```
public MyObj find(long id) {
    return myList.stream()
            .filter(obj -> obj.getId() == id)
            .map(obj -> {
                return obj;
            })
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);

}
```

I had error rendundant map call, and part of code with map function is gray. What is wrong with this? Thanks

Comment: `myList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.getId() == id).findFirst().orElse(null)`.

Comment: You might be better off with a `Map` if you're doing this alot ;).

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing, and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JoeC I disagree. The OP obviously made an effort to solve the problem. The OP described what is wrong "_I had error rendundant map call, and part of code with map function is gray_". I think this question is fine. Not an upvote deserving question, but not a downvote deserving one either.

Comment: What do you think `map(obj -> { return obj; })` accomplishes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason for including the `map` call, since it's not changing anything (it accepts a `MyObj` instance and returns the same instance).

```
public MyObj find(long id) {
    return myList.stream()
            .filter(obj -> obj.getId() == id)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);

}
```

Comment: Worth noting that returning `Optional` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Well, OP wanted `If element with that id won't found function return null`

Comment: Yeah, I know - and you have my vote. But a bit of teaching cannot hurt...